# Why is std::allocator::deallocate not noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

The C++ specification (ISO/IEC 14882:2011 + ISO/IEC 14882:2014) defines in [Table 28](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/library#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) — Allocator requirements for deallocate:

> All n T objects in the area pointed to by p shall be destroyed prior
>   to this call. n shall match the value passed to allocate to obtain
>   this memory. Does not throw exceptions.

But why is deallocate still **not** noexcept?

Comment: This is arguably a defect in the standard, and a performance bug in gcc and VS. When a `noexcept` function calls another function which is not `noexcept`, extra code has to be added by the compiler to call `terminate()` just in case of an exception. And things that `deallocate` (such as destructors) are often marked `noexcept`.  So having `deallocate` not decorated needlessly creates code bloat.  LLVM's libc++ `deallocate` is `noexcept`. This is a conforming extension, and here is how you can write a defect report to make it required: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Comment: I think my remark above about this being a performance bug in gcc is incorrect.  Further testing is revealing they optimize around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's narrow contract (causing undefined behavior if you pass it a pointer not returned by `allocate`, for instance), so per the standard library's usual policy it's not marked noexcept.

Comment: Narrow contracts are specified by [N3279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf):
A narrow contract is a contract which is not wide.  Narrow contracts for a functions or operations result in undefined behavior when called in a manner that violates the documented contract. Such a contract speci?es at least one precondition involving its 
arguments, object state, or some external global state, such as the initialization of a static object.  Good examples of standard functions with narrow contracts are vector<T>::front() and vector<T>::operator[](size_type).